# Setting up on Ubuntu server for PXE Lan install for installing Windows

Tags: installation, windows, lan, pxe

Computer has only Lan. How can i make on Ubuntu someking PXE server where ill put windows iso or windows cd in Ubuntu computer so that Comp With just Lan can install windows?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works, mate: http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/pxe-not-just-server-networks-anymore?page=0,1